# Get sum of two products with specific values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a problem where I select products from a table. I also want the query to select the sum of all products from that query if they have a specific value, for example: I want to get the price sum of products that have type = 1 or type = 2. So if I have 100 products and two of them have type =1 or type =2, the first product has price = 10 and the other = 25, then I want to get the value =35 from the query.

```
SELECT

product.name,
product.type,
product.price

FROM product
```

Is there a better way to do this than making a separate subquery ? The query example above is very barebones and the actual case where I'll need this is a much bigger query and using a subquery will greatly impact the performance.

Comment: Have you tried GROUP BY to group your products and select the sum(*) of the price?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need  the sum  you could try

```
 select  sum(price)
 from my_table 
 where type in (1,2)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [window function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). This allows to aggregate over all returned rows even when the query does not use grouping.

```
SELECT
    product.name,
    product.type,
    product.price,
    SUM(product.price) OVER() TotalPrice
FROM product
```

The true power of window functions is that you can also return aggregates for sub-groups, eg. include the total price for each type:

```
, SUM(product.price) OVER(PARTITION BY product.type) TotalPricePerType
```

This will show the total price for all rows with type=1, type=2 etc.

Answer (score 0):

If grouping by product alone is fine, 
then you can include conditional aggregations.

```
SELECT p.name
, SUM(p.price) AS TotalProductPrice
, AVG(p.price) AS AverageProductPrice
, SUM(CASE WHEN p.type IN (1, 2) THEN p.price END) AS TotalProductPriceOneTwoTypes
, AVG(CASE WHEN p.type IN (1, 2) THEN p.price END) AS AverageProductPriceOneTwoTypes
FROM product AS p
GROUP BY p.name
```

And then you can SUM OVER a normal SUM.

```
SELECT p.name
, SUM(p.price) AS TotalProductPrice
, SUM(CASE WHEN p.type IN (1, 2) THEN p.price END) AS TotalProductPriceOneTwo
, SUM(SUM(CASE WHEN p.type IN (1, 2) THEN p.price END)) OVER () AS TotalPriceOneTwoAllProducts
FROM product AS p
GROUP BY p.name
```

[test](https://rextester.com/MDCCR91910)